# How to selenium test multiple upload list files

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use following code :

```
ArrayList<String> listFile = setFileList(dataValue);
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.size(); i++) {
     File file = FileUtil.getFile(listFile.get(i));
     assertTrue(file.exists());
     List<WebElement> uploadFormList = driver.findElements(By.id"filer_input");
        uploadFormList.get(0).sendKeys(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
 driver.findElement(By.name"submitButton").click();
```

After click submit, it uploaded only 1 record. It should upload 5 records.
Please help me!

Comment: you are clicking on the submit button outside the for loop. It will submit only one record.

Comment: So, I click submit in the loop the upload 1 file for 1 loop is not select all list files. I want to select all file before submit. It multiple uploads.

Comment: If `input` has `multiple` attribute, try to send all files at once separated by comma

Comment: You mean Example: uploadFormList.get(0).sendKeys("Pic01.png,Pic02.png"); Yes, I do it. try to send all files at once separated by comma, but not working